# Why does assigning read and execute permissions to IIS_IUSRS grant access to NETWORK SERVICE?

Tags: iis, permissions, iis-7.5, application-pools

I have a Classic ASP site I'm trying to set up with Anonymous Authentication. Below is my current setup:

- App pool Identity: NetworkService
- Anonymous Authentication User: IUSR

Assigning read and execute permissions to the `IUSR` account and the `NETWORK SERVICE` account on the site's directory allows for anonymous access. However, for some reason the `NETWORK SERVICE` permissions can be assigned to `IIS_IUSRS` and it achieves the same effect. This seems strange to me given that the app pool is running with the NetworkService identity selected, not the ApplicationPoolIdentity identity. And using `net localgroup IIS_IUSRS` reveals that `NETWORK SERVICE` is not a member of the `IIS_IUSRS` group on the machine.

**So why would assigning permissions for `IIS_IUSRS` give access to the `NETWORK SERVICE` account?**

I thought maybe there was some strange fallback logic where it tries to use the app pool's virtual account if it can't authenticate with `NETWORK SERVICE`, but running Process Monitor reveals the w3wp.exe process successfully authenticates using `NT Authority\NETWORK SERVICE`. Any ideas?

Here is some server info if it helps:

- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Service Pack 1
- IIS: 7.5.7600.16385
- App Pool: .NET Framework v2.0, Classic Managed Pipeline, NetworkService Identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any account that is running an IIS application pool is automatically added to the `IIS_IUSRS` group during runtime.

Or more correctly, the security token for the `IIS_IUSRS` group is added to the security tokens for the process running any application pool.

Looking at the static membership of the  `IIS_IUSRS` group gives you the wrong idea of what is going on.

If you look at the security tab in Process Explorer, you should see `BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS` as one of the groups of the `w3wp.exe` process.

Comment: So does that mean that assigning permissions to IIS_IUSRS will always work because it gets added to the security tokens regardless of what Identity I select for my app pool? What you're saying seems to make sense, though I was unable to see the IIS_IUSRS account in Process Explorer. Is there a way to view the security tokens at run-time? I would feel much better if I could just see that IIS_IUSRS was being used in action.

Comment: I don't have an 2008 R2 Server around, but it is my understanding that you should see ` IIS_IUSRS` on the security tab in Process Explorer. These are all the security tokens of that process. On 2016 with Classic Pipeline and network service, it does show up.

Comment: Sorry, I was using Process Monitor, not Process Explorer. After switching to Explorer I do in fact see the IIS_IUSRS group in the security groups. Thanks for explaining that, it's been driving me crazy all day with this permission inception.